# Showing that each basis is also a subbasis

Tags: general-topology

While this might be a trivial question, I was wondering that is the proof of why each basis is also a subbasis the fact that if $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is a topological space and $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{T}$, then by definition each $U \in\mathcal{T}$ can be written as a union $U = \bigcup_{B \in S}B$ for some $S \subset \mathcal{B}$. Therefore $U = \bigcup_{B \in S}B = \bigcup_{B \in S}B \cap B$ so that $U$ is now union of the finite intersections of the elements of $\mathcal{B}$, making $\mathcal{B}$ a subbasis.

Comment: Yes. You could also just leave $B$ as it is instead of writing $B \cap B$, since $B$ is the intersection of the finite family of sets $\mathcal{F}$ which consists only of $B$, i.e. $\mathcal{F} = \{ B \}$ and $\bigcap \mathcal{F} = B$.

Answer (score 1):

If $(X,\mathcal T)$ is a space and $\mathcal{S}$ is a collection of open subsets of $X$ we call $\mathcal{S}$ a subbase for $\mathcal{T}$ iff $\mathcal{T}$ is the minimal topology on $X$ that contains $\mathcal{S}$ as a subfamily.

It turns out that in that case the set $$\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{S})=\{X\} \cup \{\bigcap_{i=1}^n S_i\mid n\in \Bbb N; \forall 1 \le i \le n: S_i \in \mathcal{S}\}$$ forms a base for $\mathcal{T}$ (some texts even define the intersection of $0$ sets as $X$ and then the extra $\{X\}$ is not needed as we can just say all finite intersections of subfamilies of $\mathcal{S}$). Some texts (the OP's perhaps?) even take this formulation (which is equivalent) as the *definition* of a subbase.

If $\mathcal{B}$ now is any base for $\mathcal{T}$ it is clear that any topology $\mathcal{T}'$ on $X$ that contains $\mathcal{B}$ must contain $\mathcal{T}$ as the topology $\mathcal{T}'$ is closed under unions. This makes $\mathcal{B}$ a minimal generating set for $\mathcal{T}$ as I defined and thus a subbase for $\mathcal{T}$ as well. Or altenatively note that $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{B})$ as we can take $n=1, S_1=B$ for any $B \in \mathcal{B}$. And an open superfamily of a base for $\mathcal{T}$ is still a base for the same $\mathcal{T}$. Which is what the OP's argument comes down to.